# Antlr4 ignore certain trees

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am using ANTLR4 to make a programming language(C# runtime).
However, when I tried to make a for-loop. What happened is:

1. It detects the for-loop syntax
2. Listener enters and executes it properly
3. It then visits down to the block and performs it again... and out of the scope too(as it happens later)

How can I prevent that third thing from happening?

P.S

*Is there a built-in linter/compiler* pattern in ANTLR4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners automatically visit all nodes, just once and depth-first.  This is great for doing things like semantic evaluation, but it isn't what you want for execution.

For that, you'll want to take a look at Visitors.  With a Visitor, it's up to you to decide whether to visit the children of any given node and even how many times you visit that child.

Comment: Thank you. And another question about listeners if I may, when should I use the Enter rule and when should I use the Exit one??

Comment: @1Mangomaster1 One question at a time (Q&A style), please. Open a new question and we will be able to help properly. Btw. accept an answer when it helped you and upvote it, if you think it's worth it.